# Can someone help me understand this combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

Each of m distinct points on the positive y-axis is joined by a line segment to each of n distinct
points on the positive x-axis. Except at the endpoints, no three of these segments meet in a
single point. Derive formulae for

(i) the number of such line segments;

(ii) the number of points of intersections of the segments, ignoring intersections at the endpoints of the segments.

If m = n > 2, and the two segments with the greatest number of points of intersection, and
the two segments with the least number of points of intersection are excluded, prove that
the average number of points of intersection per segment on the remaining segments is
$$ \frac{n^3-7n+2 }{4n+8}$$

i) I believe that the number is mn as for each of the m points on the y-axis, there are n possible lines.

ii) This part I don't fully understand but here is my attempt:

To have an intersection you must have 4 distinct points, 2 from the y-axis and 2 from the x-axis.
The 2 from y-axis you can choose in $m(m-1)$ ways and for x-axis you can choose the 2 in $n(n-1)$ ways.

Hence to get the total number of possible combinations of 4 points you simply get $nm(n-1)(m-1)$.

But this includes repeats as you can you want the number of distinct groups of 4 points. Now since the group of 4 points is split into 2 groups of 2 there are 4 ways to rearrange the points by taking the y-axis points and swapping them or the x-axis points and swapping them so we divide by 4 to get $$ \frac{nm(n-1)(m-1) }{4}$$
If someone could check my working for ii) I would be thankful, I am not very experienced in combinatorics so I don't know if I just typed a bunch of nonsense.

For the final part I drew a simple graph by just taking 3 points on the y and x axes to get some intuition.

I named the points on the x axis N1,N2...Nn and on the y axis M1,M2...Mm.

Considering a line from say N2 to M2, the only line segments that can intersect it N1-M3,N1-M4 and so on until N1-Mm, then I reasoned that symmetrically the other possible intersectins would be M1-N3, M1-N4 and so on until M1-Nn.

A quick look at the line N3-M2 confirmed my theory that the lines that can intersect any random line Np-Mq are the ones where:

1)Subscript of Nq
2)Subscript of N>p and Subscript of M<q

More intuitively, the 2 points have to "cross" the line segment in order to intersect it.

The number of combinations of these should be $(p-1)(m-q)+(q-1)(n-p)$
Now looking at the graph it seems like if $n=m$ then the lines N1-Mm and M1-Nn have the most intersections and I couldn't find a better way to maximise this expression so I just went with setting $p=1$ and $q=n$.
Expanding gives $(n-1)^2$ and the other line with the most intersections should be $p=n$ and $q=1$ which comes to $(n-1)^2$ also. The two lines N1-M1 and Nn-Mm always have 0 intersections so thats the 2 minimums taken care of.

Overall, taking away the 2 line with most intersections and 2 with least intersections leaves us with $n^2-4$ lines and $ \frac{(n^2)(n-1)^2 }{4}-2(n-1)^2$ total intersectins.

And this is where I get stuck because the average number of intersections should be $$\frac{(n^2-8)(n-1)^2 }{4(n^2-4)}$$ but I can't get it simplified to the required expression.

If somebody could find the flaw in my logic I would be thankful and if this is simply an algebra issue then please show me how to get to the end.

Comment: Do you expect that we solve all exercises fot you?

Comment: Apologies, I shouldn't simply post the question. I'll add my own working.

Comment: Your ii) looks good to me. When choosing $2$ points from each axis, you may also say there are $\frac{m(m-1)}{2} = \binom m2$ combinations (and correspondingly for $n$). This division by $2$ twice replaces your division by $4$.

Comment: Then any thought on the extra question about average intersections per segment?

Comment: I've developed the question almost to the end but I don't seem to get the same expression as they do. I'm editing the question now.

Comment: For the last question, I use the number of remaining intersections $\dfrac{n^2(n-1)^2}4 - 2(n-1)^2 + 1$ and got the given average. The $+1$ because when subtracting $(n-1)^2$ twice, you have also subtracted the one intersection of $N_1-M_m$ and $M_1-N_n$ twice.

Comment: Thank you so much! This question has been driving me crazy for so long. That's such an easy detail to miss, I guess I should have checked with my drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Your ii) looks good to me. When choosing $2$ points from each axis, you may also say there are $\frac{m(m-1)}{2} = \binom m2$ combinations (and correspondingly for $n$). This division by $2$ twice replaces your division by $4$.

For the last question, I use the number of remaining intersections $\dfrac{n^2(n-1)^2}4 - 2(n-1)^2 + 1$ and got the given average. The $+1$ because when subtracting $(n-1)^2$ twice, you have also subtracted the one intersection of $N_1-M_m$ and $M_1-N_n$ twice.

$$\begin{align*}
\text{No. of remaining intersections} &= 
\frac{n^2(n-1)^2}4 - 2(n-1)^2 + 1\\
&= \frac{(n^2-8)(n-1)^2+4}{4}\\
&= \frac{n^4 -2n^3+n^2-8n^2+16n-8+4}{4}\\
&= \frac{(n-2)(n^3-7n+2)}{4}\\
\text{No. of remaining segments} &= n^2 - 4 = (n-2)(n+2)\\
\text{Average} &= \frac{n^3-7n+2}{4(n+2)}
\end{align*}$$